# 500 Internal Server Error jersey rest

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

Developing jersey rest web service. I need to send json output in the below format. i have also pasted my java objects below. But my code is not able to convert my java objects to json.I guess my java objects are not properly annotated

```
{result:[2]
 {city:[         
        cityId : "",             
        cityDesc:"",
         ] 
        area:[           
        areaId : "",             
        areaDesc:"",
         ]           
        userId : ""},
    {city:[      
        cityId : "",             
        cityDesc:"",
         ] 
        area:[           
        areaId : "",             
        areaDesc:"",
         ]           
        userId : ""}}
```

Below are my java objects

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "area", propOrder = {
        "areaId",
        "areaname"})

    public class Area {

        private String areaId;
        private String areaDesc;
        public String getAreaId() {
            return areaId;
        }
        public void setAreaId(String areaId) {
            this.areaId = areaId;
        }
        public String getAreaDesc() {
            return areaDesc;
        }
        public void setAreaDesc(String areaDesc) {
            this.areaDesc = areaDesc;
        }


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "city", propOrder = {
        "cityId",
        "cityName"})
public class City {

    private String cityId;
    private String cityDesc;
    public String getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }
    public void setCityId(String cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }
    public String getCityDesc() {
        return cityDesc;
    }
    public void setCityDesc(String cityDesc) {
        this.cityDesc = cityDesc;
    }

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Response", propOrder = {
        "userId",
        "city",
        "area"})
public class Response {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String userId;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected City city;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Area area;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Result", propOrder = {

})
public class Result {

    private List<Response> result = new ArrayList<Response>();

    public List<Response> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Response> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
```

My resource method id as below

```
@autowired
private C c;

    @POST
    @Path("/bil")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Result collBil(@Valid Input input){
        Result result = new Result();
        String username=iInput.getUserName();

        if(null != username){
            try{
            result=c.getId(username);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Am using jersey framework. Am able to successfully return the Result type from my function. But after that in the rest client when i check my its throwing up 500 error. No exceptions thrown in any of my methods. But my java objects are not converted to json. Any help appreciated

Comment: If you got error 500 on the client side you **must have** an error in the server part - so go check the logs! Also, there may be something wrong in your JAXB mappings: you have a Result class, a Response class, an Area class - but the JSON pasted is simply a list of cities

Comment: i have edited my json. I need in the above format. I need list of Response class as my json output. i dont see error in server side. Once i return from end point. Jersey takes over the job of converting to json. Its throwing issue some where over there

Comment: When you receive an error response on the client (especially 500 Internal Server Error), that means you need to read the logs on your server to find the details of the error.

Comment: it will be helpful if someone validate the java objects i have written. Am not getting logs in my console

Comment: Your so -called JSON is not even valid JSON format. What makes you think you need that format. Show your resource method, what type is it expecting? Show your client code.

Comment: All i need is list of response class in my json output. Am checking the above webservice from chrome advanced rest client. I have added my resource method

Comment: What is `Input`? Since the method is not being entered I would imagine it's an error with the post data. Please show the input JSON, and the `Input` class. Also you can do some debugging on your own by using an `ExceptionMapper<Exception>` to log exceptions. Sometimes whatever exception occurs is not handle and just results in a server 500, which is not very helpful. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6567)

Comment: Resource Method is entered and the result is returned from the resource method. it is not issue with post data. After return from the resource method exception is thrown in some jersey jars. @peeskillet is there any issue with my java objects?

Comment: The only thing I really see wrong is that you are using `
`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`. This shouldn't be required as you have properties (getters/setters), which will cause a duplication error in JAXB. But this is for JSON, where the annotations may not matter. I'm not sure. It would help if there was a stacktrace. Like I said, try to register the `ExceptionMapper<Exception>`. I'm about 80 percent sure that the exception will be caught and logged from there, if you just print the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    private String username;

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    @JsonProperty(value = "Username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "Username")
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

and add `jackson-all-1.6.1.jar` to your dependencies.
and in your `web.xml`

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <!-- <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> -->
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restful.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

and in your `REST` class

```
 @POST
 @Path("/post")
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
 public Response getUserName(User user) {
     return Response.status(201).entity(user).build();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your classes Area, City, Response and Result most likely needs to have a zero argument constructor.